# Benchmarking with Python

Tags: python

I am looking to use Python as a system to benchmark other process's time, data I/O, correctness, etc. What I am really interested in is the accuracy of the time. For example

```
start = time()
subprocess.call('md5sum', somelist)
end = time()
print("%d s", end-start)
```

Would the sub process add a considerable overhead to the function being called.

EDIT

Well after a few quick tests it appears my best option is to use `subprocess` however I have noted by included stdout/stderr WITH the communicate call it adds about `0.002338 s` extra time to the execution.

Comment: Sidenote: are you aware of ``/usr/bin/time -v``?

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yes, however that may not always be available for the systems I wish to test.

Comment: odd that you have python there though. ``</endofofftopic>``

Comment: measure the `subprocess` time of a no-op program and see if it's small enough

Comment: @JBernardo Working on that now.

Comment: A couple of things to consider: Use time.time() on linux, time.clock() on windows for a high resolution timer. They returns floats, so use some form of %f if you want to print in sub-second accuracy. If multi-second accuracy is okay for you, then subprocess.call is plenty fast. In your example, stdout and stderr print to the screen. This will affect timing if there is a lot of output.

Comment: @tdelaney Good call on the `time.clock()` for Windows I would never have thought of that. However what do you mean by multi-second accuracy for subprocess.call?

Comment: @Blackninja543 I just meant that if you only care about integer deltas (%d) then the subprocess overhead is trivial. For example, my current project takes 17 minutes to build. If I can cut that down to 14 minutes, I'd be a hero. I don't care about seconds or the subprocess overhead while experimenting with solutions.

Comment: @tdelaney Force of habit, it should have been `%f`. Anyway I have come to the realization that the overhead for the subprocess call is meaningless for the tests I am performing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('yourfunction')
```

**Update**

If you are in linux, then you can use `time` command, like this:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen(['time', 'md5sum', somelist], shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print result
```

Comment: Thats not particularily helpful if you want to call subprocesses (as it adds another layer of overhead)

Comment: @JonasWielicki But, better than `start` and `end`.

Comment: @ATOzTOA My whole reason for not using the `time` command was it may not always exist in the same form. My reason for using Python is I know 2.6 will always exist in the environments I will be working with.

Answer (score 0):

If your timer script doesn't care about the stdout/stderr of the programs it times, just pipe the output to files or to /dev/null. This avoids the overhead of reading the steams and turning them into python strings.

```
start = time()
subprocess.call(['md5sum'] + some_list, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
delta = time.time() - start
```

Avoid communicate() if you don't need to read stdout and stderr as separate streams. It spawns a second thread to read stderr which adds to the overhead.