# my code stuck in an infinit loop but i dont understand the reason

Tags: python-3.x

when im trying to run my code hes entering an infinit loop and i don't understand why

EDIT:
after getting some help its seems that the script produce really large numbers and taking a lot of time doing the math. is there a way to speed it up? give it more computing power or somthing like that?

here's the code

```
def encrypt(m):
    return pow(m, e) % n


def decrypt(c):
    df =  pow(c, modinv(e, (p-1)*(q-1))) % n
    print(df)
    return pow(c, modinv(e, (p-1)*(q-1))) % n


def egcd(a, b):

    while a != 0:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)
    return (b, 0, 1)


def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g == 1:
        return x % m

def TestRSA(testnum):
    c = encrypt(testnum)
    if decrypt(c) == testnum:
        score = 'good'
    else:
        score = 'bad'

    return score

tnum = 123456
p = 17389
q = 22307
n = p * q
e = 65537
#d = modinv(e, (p-1)*(q-1))



print(TestRSA(tnum))
```

i dont understand why this this happening and if the error is in my code or in the syntexs.
please help!!!

Comment: @Carcigenicate but because of the return the while stops no ? so it is an if in fact (I never programmed in python anyway)

Comment: This feels much too broad for [SO]. It looks like you need to benchmark your code to find the hotspots (and figure out if you are CPU, memory, or IO bound) and then investigate what you can do to reduce that load. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14905800/1531971 among others. Maybe if you can isolate what the problem is, you can re-ask the question about how to make that code better...

Comment: *Works without visible result in the time my patience runs out* is not the same as (literally) `[infinite] loop` - did you check the recursion terminates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if I add some print I see :

- *decrypt* is called with 102070033 computed by *encryp*
- *modinv* returns 247312889
- so you do `pow(102070033,247312889)` and it is normal it takes time to do !

---

I am not a python programmer but when I look that :

> ```
> def modinv(a, m):
>   g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
>   if g == 1:
>     return x % m
> ```

a return seems missing when g is not 1, no ?

Comment: after getting some help its seemsms that the script prduce really large numbers and taking a lot of time doing the math. is theres a way to speed it up? give it more computing power or somthing like that?